# cannot resolve the error ProgressPlugin TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm getting an error during npm run build

here is the error

```
 Compiling client

    E:\ui\sheraspace_ui\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:223

    compilation.hooks.addEntry.tap("ProgressPlugin", entryAdd);

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined
```

I tried to delete package.lock.json and node module and then reinstalled npm.I also tried installing webpack.My project is build on next.js But I am still getting this error.Any way i can solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing "webpack" from package.json, remove package-lock.json and node_modules directory. Then reinstall the packages with `npm install`

Source: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5781

Comment: I created a new ASPNetCore project from a project template of another project. This was my solution.